# Circular dependency error for beans in Spring org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:

Tags: spring

I have a classes defined as follows :

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig extends IntegrationTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public TestUserManager testUserManager() {
...
    }
```

```
@Configuration
@Import({BaseTestConfig.class})
public class IntegrationTestConfig {

 @Autowired
    private TestUserManager ssbTestUserManager;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"testUserManager"})
    public TestDeviceFactory testDeviceFactory() {
        return new TestDeviceManager();
    }
```

```
@Configuration
public class BaseTestConfig {

   @Bean
    public TestUserManager testUserManager() {
       ...
    }
}
```

When I try to execute it, it gives the error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ssbTestUserManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testUserManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference
```

How can I fix this issue? I am not able to override the testUserManager() method in TestConfig since it does not directly inherit from BaseTestConfig. IntegrationTestConfig and BaseTestConfig are imported as libraries so I dont have much control there.

I think `@DependsOn({"testUserManager"})`  is causing issue but not sure how I can resolve it

Comment: You inject a bean into the parent class and define it in the child class, what does your mean?

Comment: @HosseinMobasher, I want to have my own definition of testUserManager in child class TestConfig

Comment: Are you using the TestUserManager instance in the parent class?

Comment: @HosseinMobasher in IntegrationTestConfig, we are using ssbTestUserManager, but in  BaseTestConfig i dont see any bean with that name so I guess it will take testUserManager() only

Answer (score 0):

A circular reference occurs when you have a chain of beans that depends together and a [cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) created in the dependency graph.

So, in your case, you've defined an instance of `TestUserManager` in `TestConfig` class and uses it in the parent class and it creates a cycle!

The solution is defininig abstract `getTestUserManager` method in the parent class and override it in the child class with `@Bean` annotation (If you are using it in other parts of code). You can use that method in your parent class instead of using the variable you've defined.

IntegrationTestConfig:

```
@Configuration
public abstract class IntegrationTestConfig {
    public abstract TestUserManager getTestUserManager();
}
```

TestConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig extends IntegrationTestConfig {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public TestUserManager getTestUserManager() {
        return new TestUserManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without editing IntegrationTestConfig ? Like i mentioned IntegrationTestConfig and BaseTestConfig have been imported as libraries and hence cannot be edited

Comment: also shouldnt the usage of TestUserManager in IntegrationTestConfig be satisfied by its parent import BaseTestConfig? Not sure why it is should show error for its child

Comment: Would you try `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` properties? Your `BaseTestConfig` defines the `testUserManager` and in `TestConfig`, you are trying to create bean again.